# The value of a variable is evaluated as an arithmetic expression when it is referenced, or assigned

Tags: bash

From bash manual

> Shell variables are allowed as operands; parameter expansion is
>   performed before the expression is evaluated. Within an expression,
>   shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the
>   parameter expansion syntax. A shell variable that is null or unset
>   evaluates to 0 when referenced by name without using the parameter
>   expansion syntax. **The value of a variable is evaluated as an
>   arithmetic expression when it is referenced, or when a variable which
>   has been given the integer attribute using ‘declare -i’ is assigned a
>   value.** A null value evaluates to 0. A shell variable need not have its
>   integer attribute turned on to be used in an expression.

What does "The value of a variable is evaluated as an
 arithmetic expression when it is referenced, or when a variable which
 has been given the integer attribute using ‘declare -i’ is assigned a
 value" mean?

Is the variable assumed to be used as an operand in an arithmetic expression?  `var=3+4` alone will not be evaluated as an arithmetic expression.

Can you give an example for the case "when it is referenced", and an example for the case  "when a variable which
 has been given the integer attribute using ‘declare -i’ is assigned a
 value"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“When it is referenced” means “when it is used”, *i.e.* the context indicates that the variable’s value should be interpreted as a number:

```
$ i=Hello
$ echo ${i}
Hello
$ echo $((i + 1))
1
```

Here `i` obviously contains a string, but because it’s used in an arithmetic expression, it’s interpreted as an arithmetic expression. If `Hello` is unset or null here, then it becomes 0; you can try playing around with different values for `i` and `Hello` to see the effects (`i=1+1`, `Hello=Hello` etc.).

Variables with the integer attribute, *i.e.* variables declared using `declare -i`, are coerced to integers on assignment, not on use:

```
$ declare -i i
$ i=Hello
$ echo ${i}
0
```

Note that in all these cases, no errors are reported.

Integer-attribute variables can be used with arithmetic expressions without any syntactic sugar:

```
$ declare -i i
$ i=3+4
$ echo ${i}
7
```

which is a direct consequence of the fact that their assignments are interpreted as arithmetic expressions.

Comment: It's treated as `0` only if `$Hello` is unset or set to something that evaluates to 0. `Hello` is a valid arithmetic expression. If `$Hello` contained `Hello + 1`, `bash` would complain about the infinite recursion.

Comment: Oh wow, I did not know that... So there’s an additional level of indirection!

Comment: It's recursive. Also note that command substitutions may be run via that mechanism, so arithmetic evaluation upon uncontrolled data is a command injection vulnerability.

Comment: It's more that when an arithmetic expression contains a variable name (including array members like `a[2]`, and even (hence the ACE) `a[\`reboot\`0]`), then its content is evaluated as an arithmetic expression and the result substituted. But as a whole, it's different from using `$var`. For instance `a=1+1; echo "$((a * 3)) $(($a * 3))"` outputs `6 4`. One can play with things like `a=a=b++ b=1 bash -c 'echo "$((++a)) $b"'`

Comment: Note that in `i=1+1; typeset -i i`, the arithmetic expression is evaluated upon `typeset` in `ksh93`, `zsh` and `mksh`, but not in `bash`.

Comment: The examples in @StéphaneChazelas's comment above have been asked about separately: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/382251/135943