# Understand two examples using indirect expansion for variable expansion in arithmetic expressions

Tags: bash

Stéphane Chazelas gave two examples in [The value of a variable is evaluated as an arithmetic expression when it is referenced, or assigned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381948/the-value-of-a-variable-is-evaluated-as-an-arithmetic-expression-when-it-is-refe#comment678699_381950)

```
$ a=1+1; echo "$((a * 3)) $(($a * 3))"
6 4

$ a=a=b++ b=1 bash -c 'echo "$((++a)) $b"'
2 2
```

I understand there is indirect expansion for variable expansion in arithmetic expressions. But I can't figure out

- how do `a` and `$a` in the first example  result in such a difference? 
  My confusion comes from that in arithmetic expressions, parameter expansion of a variable doesn't need `${}`, just write the variable directly.
- how is the arithmetic expression in the second example evaluated?

Thanks.

Comment: Because `1+1*3` equals 4 by order of operations.  For the second one, I have no idea.

Comment: For the first example, my confusion is that In arithmetic expressions, parameter expansion of a variable doesn't need `${}`, just write the variable directly.

Comment: In one case, the value of `a` is parsed before it's placed into the context of `((a * 3))`, yielding `((2 * 3))`, which evaluates to six.  In the other, it is dropped in unparsed, so it is dropped in as `(( 1+1 * 3 ))` at which mathematical order of operations takes hold.

Comment: Both examples are ilegal and a shell that does not flag them as bad is questionable. Neither `1+1` nor `b++` are numbers, but they have to be numbers  if they are referenced via a construct like `$((var))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) isn’t the same as [arithmetic evaluation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html#Arithmetic-Expansion).

In an arithmetic expression, a text string such as `a` is interpreted as a variable name, and the value of that variable is processed as an arithmetic expression itself, and the result used in the containing arithmetic expression. Thus

```
$((a * 3))
```

causes the value of the variable `a`, `1+1`, to be evaluated as an arithmetic expression, yielding `2`, and the whole expression becomes `$((2 * 3))`, *i.e.* `6`.

In the same context, `$a` is replaced with the value of `a` as-is, in an earlier phase (*this* is parameter expansion); so

```
$(($a * 3))
```

becomes `$((1+1 * 3))`, which is `4` following the usual precedence rules.

In the second example, `$((++a))` is processed before `$b` (processing takes place from left to right). The arithmetic expression causes `a` to be evaluated as an arithmetic expression itself, as above; the value of `a` is `a=b++`, which when evaluated, assigns the value of `b` (itself evaluated as an arithmetic expression) to `a`, then increments `b`. Thus after evaluating `a`, `b` is `2` and `a` is `1`. Evaluating `$((++a))` increments `a` and returns its value, which is now `2`. `$b` is just replaced with the value of `b`, `2` as well. After the quoted argument to `echo` is processed, the `echo` is run with `2 2` as its sole argument, producing the output you saw.